# Pivot table - deselect less than a value

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

On my pivot table (all items selected). I need to deselect everything lower than `11`

```
(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,(blank),(none))
```

Im currently using (below)

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Count")
    .PivotItems("10").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("9").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("7").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("6").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("5").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("4").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("3").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("1").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("none").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
```

... - it works, But if one of the values defined are not available, this doesnt work.

Is there an easier way to deselect items less than a particular value?

example: 
 `= if "8"` is on the list - `then` deselect it, `else` ignore.
or perhaps

```
 = .PivotItem("<11").Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 10 To 0 Step -1
        .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0
```