# Pivot table - Filter out any number less than a value

Tags: vba, excel

On my pivot table with all items selected, I need to deselect every value less than 10. This is what I got as of now but if one of the values defined are not available, this vba will not work.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Count")
.PivotItems("10").Visible = False
.PivotItems("9").Visible = False
.PivotItems("8").Visible = False
.PivotItems("7").Visible = False
.PivotItems("6").Visible = False
.PivotItems("5").Visible = False
.PivotItems("4").Visible = False
End With
```

Ideally i want something like this:

```
= .PivotItem("<10").Visible = False
```

I have seen someone on the forum do a For Next loop shown below, however it was not correct. The loop was counting up to the number of values to hide rather than the numbers it needs to hide.

```
`On Error Resume Next
For j = 0 To 10 Step 1
    .PivotItems(j).Visible = False
Next j
On Error GoTo 0
```

For example: I have values number 4 to 10, like the example above. If j = 5:

This loop filters out the 5th value, which is the number 8 (not what I want)

```
.PivotItems(5).Visible = False
```

While the code below is filtering out the value 5 (which is what I want). The quotes makes a big difference.

```
.PivotItems("5").Visible = False
```

I'm revisiting a problem that still has no correct solutions. Can someone please help?

[Pivot table - deselect less than a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021140/pivot-table-deselect-less-than-a-value)

Comment: Look into *value filters*. Macro recorder might be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Dim pt as PivotTable
Dim pf as PivotField
Dim pi as PivotItem

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Count")

For each pi in pf.PivotItems
   If pi.Value < 10 Then pi.Visible = False
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! Can you help make pi.value = false if it detects NA and (blanks) as well?

Comment: @KennyT. - that is really a separate question, but you can probably add some `Or` statements, like this: `If pi.Value < 10 or pi.Value = "NA" or pi.Value = "(blank)"`. You may have to play with it a bit by looping through all the pivot items when blanks and NA are there and do a `debug.print pi.Value` to see exactly what it shows to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Important Issue: Filter section of Pivot Table must be active if you want to run `PivotItem.Visible = False`